# What does "ejecting CRNA app is not reversible" really mean?

Tags: create-react-native-app

I've read [some docs](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md) that says that ejecting a Create React Native App (CRNA) is irreversible. Im not sure what this means exactly.

- Will I not be able to build my apps again for App Store, Play Store? Is it just a 1-time feature?
- Will I lose files/ code that prevents me from ejecting a second time?

I'm trying to dig a little deeper into this. If anybody could share links to relevant blogs or forums, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Ejecting is irreversible in the sense that if you modify the ejected project, you cannot convert it back into a CRNA project (except by creating a new CRNA project and copy/pasting all your code)

You can build for the App Store/Play store from a CRNA or an ejected project. For CRNA you would usually use exp:build and for ejected apps you could build from XCode. If you're only ejecting to get a standalone app, don't do it! Check out [Expo's building standalone apps](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/building-standalone-apps.html).

If you're worried about ejecting and losing you're original CRNA project, I recommend duplicating it before ejecting.

There's no reason to eject more than once. If you've ejected you can continue working on the ejected project.